# AS3 with(){} - any way to refer to the object in ()?

Tags: actionscript-3, with-statement

Can I refer the thing I just mentioned in with() with a reserved variable or something? Or do I have to write the entire thing out?

```
with(something){
someFunction(something)
}
```

In this example it's simple, but sometimes it's really long and I would like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it was javascript, then you could use valueOf(). I don't know if AS3 supports that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, see this [actionscript reference page on help.adobe.com](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#with):